# How to exit from an infinite loop without pressing Ctrl+Break in Turbo C++

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I want to make a stop-watch in C (live Stop-watch) without using inbuilt function "Timer" in Turbo C. My code is as follows:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<dos.h>

 int main()
 {
 int hh,mm,ss;
 hh=mm=ss=0;
 gotoxy(10,10);
 printf("\nSTOP - WATCH: ");
 gotoxy(20,18);
 printf("HH : MM : SS");
 _setcursortype(_NOCURSOR);
 for(;;ss++) //An infinite loop
 {
  if(ss==60)
  {
    mm++;
    ss=0;
  }

  if(mm==60)
  {
    hh++;
    mm=0;
  }

  gotoxy(20,20);
  delay(1000);
  printf("%02d : %02d : %02d",hh,mm,ss);

 }  
 return 0;
 }
```

Now I want to exit from this program on press of a button on the keyboard (lets say 'Q').

Comment: Hi, I want to let user exit from the program on the press of a single key (as we do in other programmes) and not using combination of keys!

Comment: you'll probably want to read from the system clock 2 times per second instead of using `delay(1000)`. This code will have a slight time drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kbhit()` and `getch()` from `<conio.h>` to get keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is to use `kbhit()` and `getch()`.  Should you forget, should you mistakenly compile, then your only option is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> (which probably won't work, but you might get lucky).